# Azure app service wrong redirection for new domain

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-custom-domain

I acquired a new domain name in Azure (let's say mynewdomain.net), assigned it to my app service, bought a certificate also in Azure and made the bindings. Apparently both the domain and certificate are properly configured.

When I invoke the domain in any browser like https://mynewdomain.net, I get redirected to https://mynewdomain.net/mynewdomain.net, and of course fails.

The problem must be very simple, but I have no clue! Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Thanks!

Comment: i think domain mapping has gone wrong here. this is usually a issue in the DNS records and not on azure. if I were you, I would start investigating at the DNS records from the website company where you bought the domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a [CNAME mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#create-the-cname-record) for the www subdomain, create two records: CNAME and TXT records.

After you add the CNAME and TXT records, the DNS records page looks like the following example:

[image]

To [map an A record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain#map-an-a-record), you need the app's external IP address. You can find this IP address on the app's Custom Domains page in the Azure portal.

After the records are added, the DNS records page looks like the following example:
[image]

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain) about mapping an existing custom DNS name to Azure App Service.

Comment: Fixed! I compared your the sites settings with yours and they matched. Turns out it was the code in the Default.aspx page that was manipulating the redirection based on the domain invoked as this app has multiple domains associated. Thank you very much Joey!